# Rolling three dice - sum of two results equals third one

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Is my answer correct?

> Three six-sided dice are thrown, what is the probability that the sum of two of them equals the third one?

If order does not matter, there are 9 such possibilities:

1. (1, 1, 2)
2. (1, 2, 3)
3. (1, 3, 4)
4. (1, 4, 5)
5. (1, 5, 6)
6. (2, 2, 4)
7. (2, 3, 5)
8. (2, 4, 6)
9. (3, 3, 6)

The total number of possibilities is $\frac{6^3}{3!}=6^2=36$. Therefore, the probability is $\frac{9}{36}$.

Comment: There is a problem with your assumption "order does not matter" : if you imagine there is three distinguishable dices (one red, one blue and one white), then $(1,2,3)$ corresponds to 6 different throws, but $(1,1,2)$ corresponds only to 3 different throws. So there is not uniform probability on the possibilities you enumerate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you imagine there are three distinguishable dices (either different colors, or you throw them one after the other), then there are $6^3=216$ possible cases.

Now your enumeration counts down to :

$(1,1,2)$ : $3$ cases

$(1, 2, 3)$ : $6$ cases

$(1, 3, 4)$ : $6$ cases

$(1, 4, 5)$ : $6$ cases

$(1, 5, 6)$ : $6$ cases

$(2, 2, 4)$ : $3$ cases

$(2, 3, 5)$ : $6$ cases

$(2, 4, 6)$ : $6$ cases

$(3, 3, 6)$ : $3$ cases

for a total of $45$ cases, and a probability of $\frac{45}{216}=\frac{5}{24}$.

Hope I did it the right way :-(

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have made a mistake by stating that each of these possibility is equiprobable.

Indeed, if you take into account the order of the dice, for (1,2,3) you have 6 possibilites : $(1,2,3)$, $(1,3,2)$, $(2,1,3)$, $(2,3,1)$, $(3,1,2)$ and $(3,2,1)$

However for $(1,1,2)$, you only have three possibilities which are $(1,1,2)$, $(1,2,1)$, $(2,1,1)$.

Therefore you need to consider the possibility of getting a roll with three different values (which is according to what I wrote ${6\over 6^3} = {1\over36}$) and one where two are the same (${3\over 6^3} = {1\over72}$).

Using what you stated, you get that the probability of getting a roll where two dice add up to the third is $3 {1\over 72} + 6 {1\over 36} = {5\over24}$